# inactive db fields if one of them is set to true php

Tags: php, database, symfony

Is there a way to automatically set to false the other database fields if one of them is set to true?

For example:

```
User
----

admin
is_super_admin
is_coach_admin
```

A user can only be one of the values above. If I set to true the admin, I want that is_super_admin and is_coach_admin to be set to false automatically. I mean, not to set in backend. Is there a way? At least, the best for symfony doctrine:)

Comment: You can define a default value for fields in the database. Set all to false (0).

Comment: Yes, but I meant, if I set to true the admin, then to not be able to set to true the is_super_admin or the is_coach_admin fields. There is such a way? To depend the values one of each other?

Comment: Do you want to do it on frontend? I mean, when one checkbox is set, other should be disabled?

Comment: You could very easy do it with your code when you update the table, or you could create a [trigger](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/) in MySQL for that table that handles it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson When all set to true, how the trigger knows what should be set to false? :)

Comment: @vaso123 - There must be a hierarchy. Like, if "admin" is set to true, then all others get's set to false. That would be needed regardless. However, I think I would rather create _one_ column with "role" and set that to the users role instead of creating one column for each role.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It does not help roles on the same level.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, so you suggest to create a table with the possible roles, and then to have: 

UserRole

id
user (one-to-one)
role (many-to-one) assocaited with the role table ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest that you create a "roles" table with the roles. Then you just set the ID of the role on the user. Then a user won't be able to have multiple roles and you don't need to alter the table if you add more roles. However, I would look into using some library for this since you might realize that you also need groups, fine grained control of the access etc, which quickly becomes very complex.

Comment: Yes, for now I just want that a user to have a single role, and that role to be kept in the db. I mean, when getting all coachAdmins, to do this based on some value from db. But I was concern about the relations. It doesn't make any sense to have a many-to-many relation between user and role as long as a user can have only one admin role right? So one-to-one is also great here?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve validation for your business logic (If one value is true others should be false) by the Symfony expressions:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Expression.html

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Model\User:
    properties:
        isAdmin:
            - Expression:
                expression: "this.isSuperAdmin() == false"
                message: "Admin cannot be a super admin also"
```

But if you mean to set value of one field based on another field Symfony events can be used.

```
   $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm(); 
            $data = $event->getData();             

            if ($data->isAdmin()){
                $form->get('is_super_admin')->setData(false);
                $form->get('is_coach_admin')->setData(false);
            }
        }
);
```